# Present View From Storyboard Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am very new to using Storyboards, and am trying to learn.  In my app, I want to change from one view to another, modally, without pushing any buttons, i.e. timer runs down then performs the action.  I added a notification observer in the main view, and in my storyboard, I added a new view controller, and associated the Custom Class with it called `URLWebViewController`.  In code I wrote out:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
URLWebViewController *myVC = (URLWebViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"URLWeb"];
[self presentViewController:myVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But I get the warning message

```
Incompatible pointer types sending 'URLWebViewController' to parameter of type 'UIViewController'
```

Like I said, I am very new to Storyboards, and here is what it looks like currently:

[image]

Comment: What is your URLWebViewController a subclass of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot indicates you have not created a segue between the two view controllers. Do so by click-and-drag from one view controller to the other. In the attribute inspector, give your newly-created segue an identifier, i.e., a string that names it.

To trigger this segue programmatically, in your source view controller (the one you are segueing from) just call `performSegueWithIdentifier` and pass in the identifier you chose.

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple! I didn't understand the order but let's say you want to pass from `ViewController` to `WebViewController` (the name from your storyboard)..Just ctrl-drag from `ViewController` to `WebViewController` to create a segue and select `modal` as the type.

Now click on the line that connects your view controllers and in the right panel give it an identifier. Now in your code just use the method `performSegueWithIdentifier` using the identifier you wrote.